# CSS: Why should I use ems? pxs seem to have all the same features?

Tags: css

What are the advantages and disadvantages

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS How to Properly use ems instead of pixels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555219/css-how-to-properly-use-ems-instead-of-pixels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Using_Ems

"They are resizable in all Web browsers that support resizing, they are specified relative to the user's font size preferences, and can therefore adapt to the viewer's screen."

and more...

Comment: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Using_Font_Size also has a nice comparison of the different options

Comment: so, thats it, they just adapt the the browsers default font? meh, any reason I shouldn't stick with pixels? only old people really change their font size

Comment: "only old people really change their font size" -- still laughing

Comment: I set the base font size in pixels and size with percentages after that. I've heard percentage values render more consistently across browsers. Check out http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssfonts/ By the way, I'm 24 years old and constantly resize text. Old people aren't the only ones with poor vision ;)

Comment: @DerNalia: Wrong. People don't change font size because a) it doesn't work when everyone is using the `px` unit and b) text becomes too small because people tend to set `font-size` to `.75em` or similiar when they *do* use `em`s.

Comment: @Bryan: Setting the base size in pixels is exactly what you shouldn't do. Ideally, base size should be `1em`; but any value specified in `em`s will do. Otherwise, some browsers (IE) break.

Comment: Corollary question: Is there any particular reason to use em over ex?

Comment: @You: I prefer this method (base font set in px with an IE adjustment). http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/build/fonts/fonts.css

Comment: @Bryan: CSS hacks should be avoided whenever possible; you never know if new browsers will be affected by the same hack when you don't want them to, or possibly go unaffected when you actually need the hack. It is not futureproof.